# Hide rows dynamically

Tags: pageblocktable

I am using following condition to show data on the page, if the text in the table matches a certain criteria 
then i have render condition in place that hides that text in the table . However In this code, 
when field data is hidden , that row is generated and I am getting blank row between two rows.

How to hide this row dynamically

```
<apex:outputPanel id="theform" rendered="{!AND(NOT(ISBLANK(attachmentList)),attachmentList.size>0)}">
                                                    <br/><span>To view an attached file, select the filename from the left and the action to the right<br/></span>
                                                    <apex:pageblock >
                                                        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!attachmentList}" var="a" border="1" id="pgblk">
                                                            <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
                                                                <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, a.Id)}" target="_blank" rendered="{!IF((CONTAINS(a.name,'OpportunityCertificate') && appl.createdbyId = usr.Id && appl.Request_Type__c ='Registration') || (CONTAINS(a.name,'AccountCertificate') && appl.createdbyId != usr.Id && appl.Request_Type__c ='Registration') || (appl.Request_Type__c !='Registration') || (( NOT(CONTAINS(a.name,'AccountCertificate')) && NOT(CONTAINS(a.name,'OpportunityCertificate' ))) && appl.Request_Type__c ='Registration') ,true,false)}">View</apex:outputLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                                <apex:commandLink value="" action="{!DeleteAttachment}" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(a.name,'Certificate') || !(renderFlagforDelete) || CONTAINS(a.name,'AccountCertificate') || CONTAINS(a.name,'OpportunityCertificate') ,false,true)}">
                                                                    <apex:param name="var" value="{!a.id}" assignTo="{!attachmentId}" />Delete
                                                                </apex:commandLink>
                                                            </apex:column>
                                                            <apex:column headerValue="Title" >
                                                                <apex:outputText value="{!a.Name}" rendered="{!IF((CONTAINS(a.name,'OpportunityCertificate') && appl.createdbyId = usr.Id && appl.Request_Type__c ='Registration') || (CONTAINS(a.name,'AccountCertificate') && appl.createdbyId != usr.Id && appl.Request_Type__c ='Registration') || (appl.Request_Type__c !='Registration') || (( NOT(CONTAINS(a.name,'AccountCertificate')) && NOT(CONTAINS(a.name,'OpportunityCertificate' ))) && appl.Request_Type__c ='Registration') ,true,false)}"> 
                                                                </apex:outputText>
                                                            </apex:column>
                                                            <apex:column headerValue="Description">
                                                                <apex:outputText value="{!a.Description}" rendered="{!IF((CONTAINS(a.name,'OpportunityCertificate') && appl.createdbyId = usr.Id && appl.Request_Type__c ='Registration') || (CONTAINS(a.name,'Registration') && appl.createdbyId != usr.Id && appl.Request_Type__c ='Registration') || (appl.Request_Type__c !='Registration') || (( NOT(CONTAINS(a.name,'AccountCertificate')) && NOT(CONTAINS(a.name,'OpportunityCertificate' ))) && appl.Request_Type__c ='Registration') ,true,false)}"> 
                                                                </apex:outputText>
                                                            </apex:column>
                                                        </apex:pageblockTable>
                                                    </apex:pageblock>
                                                </apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apex to filter out records you don't want to show. As we are setting the list in apex which you show using a page block table, you can filter out records in the `attachmentList`

For example: (assuming that you have an apex method similar to following)

```
public List<AttachmentWrapper> getAttachmentList() {
  List<AttachmentWrapper> allAttachments = /* get all attachments to show*/
  List<AttachmentWrapper> atwsFiltered = new List<AttachmentWrapper>();

  for(AttachmentWrapper  aw : allAttachments) {
     /*Apply filter logic - NOTOE: please double check this logic*/
     if(aw.name.contains('OpportunityCertificate') && aw.CreateById == UserInfo.getUserId() && (aw.Request_Type__c == 'Registration' || aw.Name.contains('AccountCertificate')) || ((!aw.Name.contains('AccountCertificate')) && (!aw.Name.contains('Registration'))) {
        atwsFiltered.add(aw);
     }

  }
   return atwsFiltered;
}
```